# geom_area not stacking (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-area-chart

Here is the structure of my data:

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   60 obs. of  3 variables:
$ year     : num  1990 1990 1991 1992 1993 ...
$ studyType: Factor w/ 4 levels "meta","observational",..: 2 3 3 1 3 3 3 1 3 3 ...
$ N        : int  1 4 4 1 2 5 3 1 2 6 ...
```

I'm trying to get this into a stacked area chart using the following code:

```
ggplot(evidence.summary.main, aes(x = year, y = N, fill=studyType)) + 
geom_area(alpha=.80)
```

Any ideas why I cannot get this to stack properly?

[image]

And my data from `dput`:

```
structure(list(year = c(1990, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 
1996, 1996, 1997, 1997, 1998, 1998, 1999, 1999, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2005, 
2005, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013), studyType = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("meta", 
"observational", "rct", "sr"), class = "factor"), N = c(1L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 6L, 1L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 12L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 16L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 17L, 7L, 
6L, 2L, 15L, 16L, 3L, 2L, 19L, 14L, 8L, 2L, 28L, 20L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), .Names = c("year", "studyType", "N"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: can you `dput` your dataframe?

Comment: It might be because you are missing some data.  For instance, for some of the years, you are missing data for "observational" (potentially for some of the other studyTypes as well, I did not check 100%). If you populate your data frame with the missing data (set to 0 for instance), it will probably help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @untitled that the problem is likely the missing values. I keep thinking there must be a cleaner transformation, but all I could come up with is this

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(xtabs(N~year+studyType, evidence.summary.main)), 
    aes(x = as.numeric(year), y = Freq, fill=studyType)) + 
geom_area(alpha=.80)
```

[image]

So I used `xtabs()` to basically fill in zeros for all the missing year/study combinations.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a slightly more elegant solution which relies on `tidyr::complete` which is a function that exists solely to fill in missing levels.

```
evidence.summary.main %>%
    tidyr::complete(year, studyType, fill = list(N = 0)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(year), y = N, fill = studyType)) + 
    geom_area(alpha = .8)
```